# Typescript angular 5 object inheritance

Tags: angular, oop, typescript, inheritance

I am stuck with an inheritance issue writing my first angular 5 application. I am getting the error: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'CouponEvent'. from the angular-cli

```
export class Event {
public _eventId: number;
public _type: string;
public _name: string;
public _sendDate: Date;
public _message: string;

constructor(){}

public get message(): string {
 return this._message;
}

public get type(): string {
 return this._type;
}

public get name(): string {
 return this._name;
}

public get sendDate(): Date {
 return this._sendDate;
}

public get eventId():number {
 return this._eventId;
}
}

import './Event';
export class CouponEvent extends Event {
 _expirationDate: Date;

get expirationDate(): Date {
 return this._expirationDate;
}
}
```

In my util class I am try to format the message and event.message is not found.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Event} from '../models/Event';
import {CouponEvent} from '../models/CouponEvent';

@Injectable()
export class UtilService {

formatMessage(event: CouponEvent): string {
  let msg = event.message.replace(/\${code}/gi,event.code);

  const date = event.expirationDate.toString
   msg = event.message.replace(/\${expiration}/gi,date);

  return msg;
 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This being my first time working with type script I am sort of lost why this not working.

Thank you for you're suggestions!!

Answer (score 3):

I guess that's because `Event` is a Typescript-native type, there can be some naming collision. Try to rename your class and / or `import { Event } from './Event';`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that I needed to put the classes into the same file. I had each class in its own event file. After putting the class declarations in one then it worked.

Comment: You didn't need to. The problem was in import statement. Have you seen my answer?

Comment: @DanielKucal yes. Thank you for your suggestion I really appreciate it!